# Estimated delivery date vs Estimate delivery date

Tags: american-english

I need to email a seller about how long something I ordered online will take to arrive.

Which one of these sentences is the most correct? And why?

> Do you have an **estimate** as to when my package will arrive?
>
> Do you have an **estimate delivery date?**
>
> Do you have **estimated delivery date?**
>
> Do you have an **estimated date of delivery?**

Answer (score 4):

They are all fine except the second one, which has a different meaning: *estimate* can only be a noun, so the phrase *estimate delivery date* would have to mean "date for delivery of the estimate".

Comment: Estimate can be a verb, as in "would you estimate the length of the project" but not after "an".

Comment: _Estimate_ can indeed be a verb, @DavidSiegel, but a verb cannot appear as a qualifier in a NP. ('after "an"' is not the point: this would be equally true in the plural NP "estimate[d] delivery dates").

Comment: True, a word cannot be used as a verb in a noun phrase, and starting with 'an" is only one marker for a NP. To be picky, however, "estimate[d] delivery dates" **could** be a verb phrase: "He estimated delivery dates using an inaccurate method." whereas in "90 percent of our transactions meet the estimated delivery dates." it is a NP.